# How to change Samba server description

Tags: linux, debian, samba, netbios

I just installed debian and samba my debian computer name is "debian" but after installing samba it is showing like this(in windows network places)

"Samba 4.1.17-Debian(Debian)"

How can I edit/change this description "Samba 4.1.17-Debian" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, in `[global]` section, change the following configurations:

```
netbios name = Debian
server string = Debian
```

Comment: Thanks,
I have made the change and then restarted the samba using 
/usr/sbin/service smbd restart
but network places are still showing old name will it take time to show?

Comment: @Bobby Are you using a windows client or Linux one?

Comment: I am using Windows client

Comment: @Bobby see my update